# Add webapi Header in a DelegatingHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to add a header to the request within a Delegating Handler of a webapi project
like this:

```cs
protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
{
    var corGuid = CommonBaseController.CreateSafeCorrelationId(string.Empty);
    cor = corGuid.ToString();
    request.Content.Headers.Add("correlationId", cor);
    var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
}
```

Once inside the controller I want to be able to get the header like this:

```
var cor = request.Headers["correlationId"];
```

However the header is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong Request Object. The Headers do not show up in the HttpContext.Current.Request but in the base.Request object in the Controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about storing the value in `HttpRequestMessage.Properties` instead?

DelegatingHandler:

```
request.Properties.Add("correlationId", CommonBaseController.CreateSafeCorrelationId(string.Empty).ToString());
```

ApiController:

```
var id = Request.Properties["correlationId"];
```

Comment: I get this in the controller:'System.Web.HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Properties'

Comment: @Franklin the `Properties` property sits on the `HttpRequestMessage` class in the `System.Net.Http` assembly. You seem to be in a Mvc context.